# Why more CSV values than the dimension of image?

Tags: python, csv, image-processing, export-to-csv, pixel

I am creating a `csv` file of images in dataset. Each image has dimension 40*40 pixels and all are in `.jpg` format. 
Python script is as follows:

```
for file in os.listdir("E:/ML project/10"):
    print(file)
    img_file = Image.open("E:/ML project/wiki/10/"+file)
    value = np.asarray(img_file, dtype='float32')
    value = value.flatten()
    value=value/255
    writer.writerow(value)
```

There are few images which are having more than 1600 `csv` values.

[image] Images similar to these are having 1600 values. These were cropped by python script.

[image] Images similar to it are having more than 1600 values. Is it due to forcefully compressing it to 40*40?

How do I fix it?

Comment: the `print()` prints the size too. Are ALL sizes 40x40?

Comment: Yes, checked already. Those with abnormal values weren't in aspect ratio 1:1 while resizing them to 40*40 with a third-party software.

Comment: Okay, I got it. It is due to image not completely grayscale. Thanks for that `4800` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your second sample image is in fact an RGB image and therefore has 3 * 40 * 40 values.

One way to deal with that is to convert it to greyscale using [Image.convert()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert). Actually you can do the same with all your non-greyscale images:

```
if img_file.mode != 'L':
    img_file = img_file.convert('L')
```

(BTW I would change the variable name from `img_file` to `img` or something like that)